# Listener in Spring Boot for listening(Async) the Google Pubsub message

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, listener, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created topic and subscription in google pubsub. How to read the google pub sub message from spring boot application(Subscriber? Also how to make always listening that subscription from my application to pull/read the message.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend you to take a look at [Spring Cloud GCP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_cloud_gcp_for_pub_sub). It features a Pub/Sub integration that should be just what you're looking for.

There's a sample application [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-sample).